# Hypothesis testing in multiple regression

Tags: regression, spss

I have the following variables:

1. weight (ratio scale)
2. result obtained from psychological test (eg. iq)  (ratio scale)
3. style1 (ratio scale)
4. style2 (ratio scale)
5. style3 (ratio scale)

I want to test this hypothesis:
People with high result on style 1 and high result on IQ scale are having bigger weight than people with high result on style 2 and low result on IQ scale.

Should I make a categorical variable 'style' and recode values of style 1, style 2, and style 3, and then proceed regression analysis, or there is a way to test hipothesis without this conversion.

I bet it should be multivariable regression analysis, but I don't know how to divide file in groups, when I have three variables.

Comment: Just to check I understand.  First, you say style 1 is a ratio scale, but in your text you talk about "people with style 1" which makes it sound as though it is a categorical variable they can have.  Do you mean "people with high scores on style 1?" or is it really an on/off variable?  Second, are you interested in the effect of style 1 and style 2 in general (regardless of IQ), as well as the combinations you say, or only in combination with those particular levels of IQ? (this makes a difference to the models you test).

Comment: Third, for this to be useful, you would need to somehow control for additional factors that might be related to weight.  For example, if having uneducated parents means people are more likely to adopt style1 and also means they have higher weight, a relationship between style 1 and weight would show up when really it is just a proxy for the parents they had.  You can control for this either by conducting an experiment if you can (which is unlikely) make people adopt particular styles; or, more likely, include other variables in your model like standard socio-demographic status variables.

Comment: Style1/2/3 is on ratio scale and actually I don't know if I should recode it, or leave it as it is (to get to my aim, which is checking the hypothesis:)). According to third point, the iq scale is just a example.

Comment: When you use the term ratio scale, this is what we think it means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement and a 1/2/3 scale would normally be too short, for starters.

Comment: You're right, style 1 is on ratio scale (also a measurment from psychological test), not on 1/2/3 scale, what I've written (style1/2/3) was just a shortcut, sorry for my clumsy explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I'll put aside any concerns about whether you have the right variables in your model and focus on what you ask.

From your question about separating the data into groups, I am assuming you mean (for example) creating a new variable IQ.categorical which could have three examples - low, medium or high - depending cut-off points in your original ratio variable.  From the way you have worded your hypothesis it sounds like you are thinking in these terms.  It's certainly possible to do this, and I see you have added the SPSS tag - is your question really just "how do I create a categorical variable from a continuous one, using SPSS?"

My SPSS is very basic and rusty but my recollection of this issue was that this was quite a straightforward thing to do.  One way of doing it would be to use the COMPUTE command to create a variable filled with missing values, and then more COMPUTE commands to assign new values to that variable if the original iq is in particular ranges.  Then you just check that SPSS recognises the new variable as categorical.  All this can also be done through the menus if you aren't comfortable with syntax.

Whether you do this to create one new categorical variable or 50 doesn't change the procedure.  The point is each row of your data will have a value in a new column for the categorical variable you have created.  You can then use this (instead of the original) as a variable (explanatory or response) in your modelling.

Having done that to all of your variables you can use the General Linear Model function (not to be confused with a generalized linear model) to fit your model and perform any hypothesis test you like.  For example, comparing one "full" model that includes your interaction effect you want to test to a simpler one that doesn't.

However, why would you turn your nice ratio variables into clunky categorical ones?  You lose a lot of information that way - for example, all the differences between iq that only just made it into "high" versus those who are off the range.  If the relationship between your explanatory variables and the response is complex and disjoint you may end up needing to do this, but before even contemplating that I would look at some plots of the relationships between my variables and the response, including the relationship of obvious transforms (like logarithms).  It might be that you can specify a model in the original scales or a continuous transformation of them rather than turning them into categorical variables and losing all that information.  SPSS can draw a scatterplot matrix so I'd start with that.

Comment: Nice explanation. :) I'm curious about how somebody can be one of 3 styles, all on ratio scale, but apparently if the person has a value on style 1, they don't a score on either style 2 or style 3. Maybe I need more coffee...

Comment: @Michelle: Person can have mixed styles. They're three parallel "dimensions"  describing personality.

Comment: @Luke that should have been in your question. :)

Comment: @Peter: I don't want to create categorical variables out of IQ. I want to put people in categories, whether they're style 1 or style 2 or style 3. I understand that I will loose a lot of information, so the question is, what should I do, to compare impact of three variables (iq, style1, style2) on weight, so I'll be able to prove hipothesis.

Comment: Sounds like great advice, Peter.  @Luke:  can you add an update to your question so as to make it extremely precise in its wording and so as to take into account the good questions and advice that have been offered so far?

Comment: @Peter: Probably glm is the answer, I'll start exploring it. Thanks.

Comment: I'd avoid that acronym glm in this context.  Many people use it to refer to "generalized linear model" which is quite different from what SPSS calls the general linear model.